# Custom methods for SQLAlchemy subclasses

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class `Alert` that is polymorphic on its category:

```
class Alert(Base):
    __tablename__ = "alert"
    name = Column(Unicode)
    category = Column(Unicode)
    frequency = Column(Unicode)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': category}
```

`Alert` has subclasses `TopicAlert` and `SearchAlert`, that have their own `get_results` methods:

```
class TopicAlert(Alert):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "Topic Alert"}

    def get_results(self):
        # code here

class SearchAlert(Alert):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "Search Alert"}

    def get_results(self):
        # code here
```

Whenever I add a new alert, I want to get the results and save it to a different table, that I have called `AlertResult`:

```
def add_alert(request):
    alert  = Alert()
    alert.name = request.params.get('name')
    alert.category = request.params.get('category')
    alert.frequency = request.params.get('frequency')
    Session.add(alert)
    Session.flush()

    alert_result = AlertResult()
    alert_result.alert = alert
    alert_result.result = alert.get_results()
    Session.add(alert_result)
    Session.flush()
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Alert' object has no attribute 'get_results'
```

If I add a `get_results()` method to `Alert`, then this method is always executed instead. Is it not possible to define custom methods / override inherited methods for subclasses in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: You didn't create an instance of the subclass. You created an instance of the parent class. That won't magically divert the call to a subclass here. I guess you'd have to re-query to get the new class for that row.

Comment: Requerying, i.e. `alert = Session.query(Alert).get(alert.id)` didn't help, I'm still getting the same attribute error.